# Prevent HTML Form Input File from Clearing

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Ok revised question a little, is there a way to prevent my file input from clearing. What happens is everytime I update form with value it clears the file input

FORM

```
<iframe name="my_iframe" src="" id="my_iframe"></iframe>
<form action="http://******/Update.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="my_iframe">
    <p>
        <input type="file" id="input" name="image" onchange="handleFiles()"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        text input1:
        <input type="text" name="text1" value="%%%myvalue1%%%"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        textinput2:
        <input type="text" name="text2" value="%%%myvalue2%%%"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT - THIS LOADS IMAGE INTO IFRAME TO PREVIEW

```
<script>
var img = document.getElementById("image");
var width = 450;
function handleFiles() {
    var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('input').files;
    var file = filesToUpload[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        img.onload = function() {
            if (this.naturalWidth > width) {
                this.width = width;
            }
        }
        img.src = e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
</script>
```

UPDATING - `%%%myvalue1%%%` whenever this changes, it clears the file input from form

```
myvalue1 = ""
var text = "pears"
myvalue1 = text
```

I have attached a sample app [here](http://www.i-audit-jci.com/a1b2bn3n4ma7f9/SampleForm)

Comment: I recently revised question to be less confusing, thanks

Comment: Can you provide your javascript code and also on which action your file input gets cleared

Comment: I have added the code and updated question

Comment: Is the image you are assigning `e.target.result` to somewhere outside of the given code? Also you have an invalid `input` attribute in the file input, and `onchange` should be preceded by a white-space.

Comment: Not certain what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you make it 2 separate `form`s and have the image `form` fill the `iframe` and have a second `form` to capture the 2 `textbox` field values.

Or you could have the values in the three fields in the current `form` all put there values into variables. And have the form look to see if the variables are empty before running, if they are not empty use values for you current fields in the `form`.

Comment: Great idea, after a get few variables set in form, I then will deploy camera interface to get image then I will use SQL update into database the link.  And the first form I will send first after I have obtained all information to the data to SQL dB using insert into... then I will submit 2nd form with image.  Thanks all

Answer (score 4):

I think when you where preventing or blocking the right click and other keys to prevent your code u just put the block on showing text in the input so just check your all the scripts that you are using to block key and mouse click. I Just check your all code by deleting other scripts I can see your apple and other text in the input.

Comment: I am not using mouse using touch on mobile, but if I understand you correctly, you are saying prevent user from mouse clicks. Not sure I am following what you are saying

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what exactly is happening when you set the text. It looks like setting the text either resets just the value of the file, or it is causing the form to be rebuilt with only the new text values. Again, it really depends on how you are setting the text.